# MVC 3 Entity Framework simple mapping of keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Model classes:

```
public class User {
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Asp_Membership> CreateDates { get; set; }
}

public class Asp_Membership {
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext {
        public UsersContext() : base("ApplicationServices") { }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Asp_Membership> Asp_Memberships { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
           //mapping of Users and Membership
           //what exactly do i put here to join the two tables by UserId
        }
```

My question is a simple one, and as you can probably tell, these are my first attempts into trying to understand how EF actually works. What i am trying to do is join the aspnet_Users table and aspnet_Membership table based on the UserId. How exactly can i do that?

But far more importantly, i really haven't been able to find a good Entity Framework tutorial, any recommendations?

--UPDATE--

**DbContext** (same as above)

**Model class:**

```
public class User {
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual Asp_Membership asp_Membership { get; set; }
}

public class Asp_Membership {
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
private UsersContext db = new UsersContext();

// GET: /Users/Index
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View(db.Users.ToList());
}
```

**Index page:** (with unnecessary elements removed...)

```
@model IEnumerable<ReservationPro.Models.User>
...
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.asp_Membership.CreateDate)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

All i am trying to do is figure out how to join the two separate tables 'aspnet_Users' and 'aspnet_Membership' from the default aspnetdb. As noted in the model class, they both have the column 'UserId'. I know this is a simple question, i'm sorry for making this confusing. As you can probably tell, I have just started with EF and am just trying to get my hands 'dirty' with some simple code.

Comment: Why does a user have a *collection* of memberships and why they are called *CreateDates*?

Comment: That's a very good question, check the updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the model classes in your UPDATE you can try this mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasOptional(u => u.asp_membership)
        .WithRequired();
}
```

The mapping means that a user *can* have a membership (not more than one) but it is not required (`HasOptional` / `0..1`). A membership on the other hand always *must* have exactly one related user (`WithRequired` / `1`).

In the ASP.NET membership tables the `User` table respresents the principal with the primary key of the relationship, the `Membership` table is the dependent with the foreign key. But the foreign key is the primary key (`UserId`) of the `Membership` table at the same time. So, the relationship is a shared primary key one-to-one relationship. You must define this explicitly with the mapping above, otherwise by default EF would infer a one-to-many relationship from your model.

Comment: Wow that was it. Thank you Slauma for the response. By the way, do you have any recommendations for some tutorials to look at on the fluent api?

Comment: Also, @Slauma, how did you know the Membership table is the dependent with the foreign key?

Comment: @theStig: 12-part-tutorial about `DbContext`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx Then Julie Lerman's two books (I didn't read them but everyone who did recommends the books): http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Entity-Framework-Code-First/dp/1449312942 and http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Entity-Framework-Julia-Lerman/dp/1449312969 I found the dependent by looking into a database with ASP.NET membership tables -> open relationship between User and Membership table -> FK is in Membership table, PK in User table.

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there. Try this:

```
public class User {
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual Asp_Membership asp_membership { get; set;}
}

public class Asp_Membership {
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual User user { get; set;}
}
```

This way, you'll have access from one to the other in either direction. If you only want it in one direction, just put it in the class you want to access the other from.  Also, this assumes the relationship is 1 to 1. It's kind of hard to tell from your question.

Comment: i get an error now: "Invalid column name asp_membership_UserId'."

Comment: Essentially what i am trying to do is view a table with the column "UserName" and "CreateDate" and so when i pass Users.ToList() to the view, i get that error

Comment: So there isn't a column called UserId in your Asp_Membership table?

Comment: No there is, the db is just the aspnetdb

Comment: This cannot work because you don't define if `Asp_Membership.user` belongs to `User.CreateDates` or `User.asp_membership`. Hence EF assumes there are three relationships and a default foreign key for `User.asp_membership` which is NavigationPropertyName_KeyNameInTargetClass = "asp_membership_UserId" that doesn't exist = exception. I would try to answer myself but I really don't understand the purpose of this collection...

Comment: Right good point. I ignored the Icollection of Asp_Memberships. Yeah this won't work with both. I've edited my answer but i think ultimately you're right. This question is impossible to answer with certainty without more information as to what @TheStig is trying to do.